# Difference between Literal and Dynamic arrays in Pharo 3

Tags: arrays, dynamic, smalltalk, literals, pharo

Reading the documentation of Pharo (Pharo By Example) the first difference is in the way that arrays are made.

A literal will follow this syntax

```
myArray := #(1 2 3)
```

while a dynamic array with

```
myArray := {1+2 . 4-2 . 3 }
```

A literal array will take values directly , containing numbers, strings and booleans. While a dynamic array will take full messages that will compile and insert their returning values to the array.

Is there are any other difference between the two ? Why do literal arrays exist if dynamic arrays can do what literal arrays do  ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dynamic array like `{ 1 + 2 . 4 - 2 . 3 }` is basically a syntactic sugar for:

```
Array
  with: 1 + 2;
  with: 4 - 2;
  with: 3
```

Which makes sense because arrays are created quite often. Also you can incorporate this to create a dictionary for example:

```
{
  #keyOne   -> 5 .
  #keyTwo   -> 3 .
  #keyThree -> 1
} asDictionary
```

Literal arrays as actually literal and are defined before compile time.

Comment: thank you uko, can you please define "before compile time", I have seen this also in PBE but I am not sure I understand exactly what it means

Comment: @Kilon when you "save a method" or officially: "accept changes" it is being compiled into a byte code. This is done for performance reasons, as it's faster for VM to interpret byte code commands, rather then AST itself or whatsoever. Now when you use: `2`, `@c`, `#sym`, `#(1 2 3)` and other literals, compiler knows that this things won't change and so can optimise the byte code. Whereas "dynamic array" is composed during a run time (when the byte code is executed by VM) and so you cannot do anything special about it

Comment: I see , so its about optimization and performance. Thanks its clear now.

Comment: @Kilon yes. The thing is that dynamic array is not a literal. It's one more expression on the same level as assignment, message send and cascade.

Answer (score 5):

Literal arrays are standard Smalltalk syntax, dynamic arrays are a Squeak (and therefore Pharo) extension. I believe similar syntax exists in other Smalltalks, but it's not universal.

So the reason literal arrays exist is because they always have - they're part of Smalltalk 80.  Other than syntax and when they're evaluated, I don't think there's any other difference - I believe they both result in an object of the same type, it's only how they're initialized that's different.